# Wait method in Codeception / Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

I'm following the tutorial "Web Application Development with Yii2 and PHP" where codeception is used for testings purposes (TDD).

When running a test with JavaScript validation, the tests described in the book use the `Wait(1)` method which lets the test wait for 1 second to allow validation.

It seems that this function is not supported (anymore). It exists in the documentation, but when delving into the code, the method cannot be found.

Am I doing something wrong, or did I miss a configuration change?

```php
namespace Step\Acceptance;

class Guest extends \AcceptanceTester {

    public $username;
    public $password;

    public function __construct($scenario) {
        parent::__construct($scenario);

        if ($this->username and $this->password)
            $this->login($this->username, $this->password);
    }

    function login($username, $password) { // 1
        $I = $this;
        $I->amOnPage('/site/login');
        $I->fillField('LoginForm[username]', $username);
        $I->fillField('LoginForm[password]', $password);
        $I->click('Login');
        $I->wait(1);

        $I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem here. Bump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you fix the issue?

I think it's a config issue, are you using webdriver? Maybe post your acceptance.suite.yml as well.
http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#.VwOm6xN96Rs

The wait function is in the functions list to the right.

EDIT: Your acceptance.suite.yml should have something that looks like this

```
modules:
   enabled:
      - WebDriver:
         url: 'http://localhost/'
         browser: firefox
```